# Why this cell text is not removed using this script?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
$('#tbl_det_kelengkapan tr').find('.hid_dok_pdf').each(function(i){
   var isPDFExist  =  $(this).val();
   var col_upl  = "<input type='file' name='ket_upl[]' class='ket_upl' multiple /><input type='hidden' class='hid_ket_upl' />";
   
   if(isPDFExist == null){
    //$(this).closest('tr').find('.td_upl').empty();   
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.td_upl').html("");
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.td_upl').append(col_upl);
   }
   
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tbl_det_kelengkapan" class="table table-bordered table-striped" border="1">
<tr>
<td align='center' class='td_upl'>
     <a style='text-decoration:none' class='a_pdf' href='javascript:void(0)'>
        <img id='img_success' src='data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAkFBMVEXiV0z///+1NinUTULXUEThSz7hTUDhUUb2z83iVUrxs6/yu7jrkozhTkLqj4n0xMG0MiTgRzrogHnjXVL++fnupKC2JxTzwr/gSDrla2Lsm5W2IQq1HgDFQjbgQzX43Nr65OLvqKTph4Dnd2/xuLX77Ou2JxP31tS2Lx/34eDkYljrl5Lpg3zmcGf88O/YVks8VYljAAAGe0lEQVR4nO3d64KiNhgGYHAXYlScQbGK3XoYtXScnen9311BJUBOGGDki/3eny0DeUhMwmGD48qzO07judNL6L8nRaEaxZH+1+QQ+oT2A3ScH69dEmXCaBaSvnRX4T8dEiXCk9OrLxUOuiSKwpPXW/Nkwi6JgjBy+gZmwg6JgvCt5yZ6E6bE3fcIk7Bv3004eP2jGyIvnPVfhTdhVw2VE542ffMcJuyooXLCo983zymE3RA54RRAIy2EnRA5Ydz7UOGUhV0QOeEcmLADIiek0ITtBw3wwta1CF84eP27FdECYctatEGY1uL7kwvT7qY50Q5hG6IlwhZEW4TNidYIB69/NiPaI2xaixYJG9aiTcJmtWiVMK3F7ZML01o0JlomTCdwpkTbhOZE64TGDdU+oWl3Y6HQsKHaKDSrRSuFRrVop3Dw+it5cqFBLdoqvP+3aK3wbqK9wrSh3vVbtFh4Z3djs/C+WrRamP4W64l2C++pRcuFd/wWbRfWN1TrhbVE+4V1xCcQpsShZcKfhsLBQNfdQBQ6xkJdQ30OoW7QACn8y5w4UP4WQQpNu5pLfimIIIUNmqm6FmEKzXtTNRGmsNEvUUEEKuyQCFXYkCjpbsAKO6tFuMKG3Y1Qi4CFqbFBPQrTcNDCLD9N88OzTGgc6jy9kKLQ9qAQhfCDQhTCDwpRCD8oRCH8oBCF8INCFMIPClEIPyhEIfygEIXwg0IUSvZIAj9PEMhXPS1tkm2jWRq1vGW2sfnaY50LSbAeFdlP4o3Hl4puZvvyNusZSTeSHYmG01E1B69vIXlz+Qx/h5W90LO4OmCUrKm4iigl4mJCY1Nix0J6FoqU5j0uL923USx/uDzzRk/21pbpSo4dC4ORvPTrYglNSS3nGZNK6eWna2m40GHHQulZzzJa1Z2ELNFnUNqZ/Fwkhs30UUJ3nZ96f6wWuu5bqfxkKtviBaqQLcGoF7pvRS3KhaaLVT5OuA3vErqfTCAVDnvuS5lweJhlWZT+5eon5YTbYZZkF1UO+cV6VCbcvbBMVuqDP1a4DEmWYFPUw9LjhNONlyX041EZyUY8JhxfN0zj9z6nYULWH3iTonI44YTkZQg2+9JBz5QTmg4QjxU6GzYvuZZcFF7+cFYcNP9bW4QBq57rbEQudILfwlFtERJWOx86oRMu3eqG1ghpnO9sH+iEpZLcRgRbhOSQ72ytrUPHe8n/R2SXMFjkO3vTC0vT0OsCzbYIQ9aXxpq+NCtKwA57nZlZIvQ+8n1F13IqhU7ILhwXAXwhm9OwAT9Hq4Uem+KN/Ypw7NFbAAmT6STLorSw4YHUCdm0/Xoyijok82uCBt9Ledy1xfvtMwtqoc9GxGFVWGRoXo2PE34K14dCHbLhQil0t2CuLYQsxGt8dStVC92DaSU+Snhkt6LUwhUbV5bVnqZypkyvnx4kXBSNSzNasM331dECvjAp3y9Vz2nY9I4f8csx/uLG9wujl0Plnrd6XlrcwOFmbaUY36b5NuF2ccl6OuefWyivLQi7lfF1bdOFMMpz9MGMFstNkEXyWEkl9Io7xbdZmjin8QI4I776vq1CWPoV5o8mRKExD5AwiIuD7m4jC+yZt5GQktIEvbirbb/wdr/UWznr8nPC93xyYL8wudzFHm6554lsxLNfKM+aPZp5UuGo9Cz1KYWj0sf6YAvVhfKPGuBH+fKP3XwbB6qd3ZHveo6/UBaKTFxVknPlvLB7yes2X/Dr+l2MvFCaT9KFX3LfdhZyf+TdBpFWH3vt+n2aYH35u6mmXdGz+JaMuxvFK6GmaHyZjE/aNNLu34kKPsfDUawtE/Wq70QtpjFZSefUxBkNx/qd1eYb3msL6q8ASFAJUR7mnp3VlQffTey7gK2DQhTCDwpRCD8oRCH8oBCF8INCFMIPClEIPyhEIfygEIXwg0IUwg8KUQg/KEQh/KAQhfCDQhTCDwpRCD8oRCH8oBCF8INCFMIPClEIPyhEIfygEIXwg0IUwg8KUQg//3uhZuEAW0LnWqHx6mjwQmOt0HSZfoDhV33jhOM266bACL9aDCc8bep3ATzhSSs0/qoLuJCZqxcmYf1OQCdMaoS3RbitjfitGkEYtVr+pu9QJ6oVuqcG6y9DCfXFb0uJQvfk2NpQiSP5eJZE6Eaz0EYjCWdCE1UI0x71EPqaD9zBCyX+6sD3ojph2lSP03jed7nvzjyeHhVfd3P/A537n1Q2avB1AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC' width='20px' />
     </a>
     <input type='hidden' value='' class='hid_dok_pdf' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center' class='td_upl'>
     <a style='text-decoration:none' class='a_pdf' href='javascript:void(0)'>
        <img id='img_success' src='data:image/png;base64,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' width='20px' />
     </a>
     <input type='hidden' value='X' class='hid_dok_pdf' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center' class='td_upl'>
     <a style='text-decoration:none' class='a_pdf' href='javascript:void(0)'>
        <img id='img_success' src='data:image/png;base64,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' width='20px' />
     </a>
     <input type='hidden' value='X' class='hid_dok_pdf' />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align='center' class='td_upl'>
     <a style='text-decoration:none' class='a_pdf' href='javascript:void(0)'>
        <img id='img_success' src='data:image/png;base64,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' width='20px' />
     </a>
     <input type='hidden' value='' class='hid_dok_pdf' />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I tried to remove the content of a cell using jQuery. This is the table cell html.

```
<td align='center' class='td_upl'>
     <a style='text-decoration:none' class='a_pdf' href='javascript:void(0)'>
        <img id='img_success' src='".base_url()."assets/images/pdf_icon.png"."' width='20px' />
     </a>
     <input type='hidden' value='".$row_bayar_d['FILE_UPLOAD']."' class='hid_dok_pdf' />
</td>
```

When I use this to replace the cell text value, the supposedly appended text is not appended. This is how I replace the cell text:

```
$('#tbl_det_kelengkapan tr').find('.hid_dok_pdf').each(function(i){
    var isPDFExist  =  $(this).val();
    var col_upl     = "<input type='file' name='ket_upl[]' class='ket_upl' multiple /><input type='hidden' class='hid_ket_upl' />";

    if(isPDFExist == ""){
         $(this).closest('tr').find('.td_upl').empty();   
         $(this).closest('tr').find('.td_upl').append(col_upl);
    }
});
```

The cell is emptied but the `col_upl` is not appended

Comment: $(this).closest('tr').find('.td_upl').html("");

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai it's not appended the `col_upl`

Comment: @jeevanswamy21 I've tested it and the `col_upl` is not appended. The cell is emptied though

Comment: Maybe `isPDFExist` value is not `""`

Comment: @Alexandru-IonutMihai I change the input of `.hid_dok_pdf` to `type='text'` and it has no value

Comment: What means has no value ? It is null, empty string....

Comment: the data from database is null

Comment: now, it's not emptied and still not appended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to replace the information inside the  block, right?
If so, you can: `$(this).closest('tr').find('.td_upl').html("what_you_want_to_put");`

Comment: ups.. I forget to change the `if` rule. Thank you it's working